# MySql get 10 recent comments with all sub comments

Tags: php, mysql, nested, comments

I have a comment table like

```
id | post_id | parent_id | user_id | text | time | likes
```

Comments can have 1 level sub comments(no 2nd/3rd level nesting). Users can sort comments based on time/likes.

What will be the query to get **10 recent comments** along with **all their sub comments**.

```
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `text` 
FROM `comments` 
WHERE `post_id` = '$postId' OR `parent_id` IN 
(
   SELECT `id` FROM `comments` 
   WHERE `post_id` = '$postId' 
   ORDER BY `time` DESC 
   LIMIT 10
) 
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Remove outer limit if you want to get all sub comments

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid It gives error that MySql doesn't support LIMIT subquery. As you are suggesting, removing outer limit will result in showing all top level comments, isn't it?

Comment: Share your schema please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add other conditions as needed.

```
SELECT c.`id`, c.`parent_id`, c.`user_id`, c.`text` 
FROM `comments` c,
(
   SELECT `id` FROM `comments` 
   WHERE `post_id` = '$postId' 
   ORDER BY `time` DESC 
   LIMIT 10
) temp
where c.id = temp.id or c.parent_id=temp.id
```

Comment: That is exactly what I figured out myself:)

Comment: What about ordering? .. Top level comments are returned in order by time desc ... but what about subcomments ... will they be returned in order of their ID or any random order?

Comment: If an order is not specified, there's no guarantee that they would be returned in a particular order. In case you'd like all of the comments order by time, you'll have to add an explicit `order by` clause.

Comment: I understand regarding ordering. But I have 15000 entries and this query works but seems slow. Can there be any better query to achieve the same? I was thinking of getting this done in 2 queries - 1) to get root comments 2) get their corresponding sub comments. Will that be better option?

Comment: 15000 is not a large number. Are your indexes in place? parent_id, post_id, time (individual)? You could go with the second option which means 2 queries? Measure it, I would say.